# Having Problems Installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try installing rails using `gem install Rails` I get

"ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)"

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I googled and tried several solutions but they didn't work. For example, I tried changing the source of gem to be http://rubygems.org instead of using https but I get the same error.

I'm not sure what caused this error. I have rails installed on my other computer but for some reason that too doesn't work. It has a problem fetching data from https://rubygems.org and http://rubygems.org

Answer (score -1):

Seems like I had to use a VPN to fix my problem. I'm not sure why my network is blocking access to https://rubygems.org but it works now.